# Extendscript load content from var

Tags: javascript, extendscript

In Javascript or PHP this is fairly easy but doesn't seem to work for extendscript.

I have a search function that stores it's results in a `var`. I want to see what is in the `var` after the function runs. So usually I use a `alert()` but InDesign comes up with a box containing
 `[object Word]`.

Here is what I do:

```
var myFound = myDoc.findGrep();
alert(myFound);
```

InDesign throws me this box:
[image]
If I do the following:

```
alert(myFound.length);
```

[image]
Any ideas how to "reveal" my content?

Answer (score 0):

The result of a grep search is an array. You need loop through it and access the `word.contents`

Comment: So I created the loop and get the values. Problem is that there are 113 values. So I have to click a 113 times ok. Can I get them in one overview?. This is the loop:`for(i=0; i<myFound.length; i++)
{
    var resultaat = myFound[i].contents;
    alert(resultaat);
}
`

Answer (score 0):

If someone wants to know how to fix it:

Create an array around the for loop and gather the information in it.
After that `alert` the array like this:

```
var myFound = myDoc.findGrep();

var result = new Array();

for(i=0; i<myFound.length; i++)
    {
        result[result.length] = myFound[i].contents;
    }

alert(result);
```

Comment: Ok, you can get one alert, by using `result.join(", ")`  or  `result.join("\n")`  for example.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I entirely use `$.writeln()` instead of `alert()`.

or use

[milligramme/scriptui_scrollable_alert](https://github.com/milligramme/scriptui_scrollable_alert)

Comment: Yes I understand but I'm creating a script in InDesign so `alert()` is, as far as I know, my only option!

Comment: ScriptUI is part of extendscript, so it will work in InDesign.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this site (http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6js) immensely useful in understanding ExtendScripts InDesign objects. In particular, your [Words object is here](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6js/pc_Words.html), which is an array of [Word](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6js/pc_Word.html) instances.

In addition, I've used Use [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with the [ExtendScript Debugger](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Adobe.extendscript-debug) which helpful for watching variables.